# js получастьб кастомные значение из type="radio"

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте как получить кастомные значения из кнопки type="radio" value="1" mytarval="test"

и показать выбранный результат на экран

Часть моего кода выглядит так :

```js
document.mainForm.onclick = function(){
    var radVal = document.mainForm.rads.value;
    var radVal1 = document.mainForm.rads.mytarval;
    result.innerHTML = 'You selected: '+radVal;
    result1.innerHTML = 'You selected: '+radVal1;
}
```

```html
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="1" mytarval="test1" /> one
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="2" mytarval="test2"  /> two
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="3" mytarval="test3"  /> three
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="4" mytarval="test4"  /> four
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result1"></div>
```

Вот мой mytarval - выдает ошибку, как сделать так, что бы мой атрибут значения тоже показывался на экран.

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

например так:

```
document.querySelector("#mainForm input[value='1']").getAttribute('mytarval')
```

или так:

Например так:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("#mainForm input")

for (let obj of elements) {
    console.log(obj.getAttribute('mytarval'))
}
```

```html
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm">
    <input id = 'xxx' type="radio" name="rads" value="1" mytarval="test1" /> one
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="2" mytarval="test2"  /> two
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="3" mytarval="test3"  /> three
    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="4" mytarval="test4"  /> four
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result1"></div>
```